# Changing multiple values in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, case, where-clause

I need to change the value of a specific field/column of multiple records and between specific dates, in a MySQL table.  Using the MySQL workbench v5.2.  So for example  I need to check if the value is over x, between two specific dates.  If it is over x, then I need to make it = y.  I was trying the below statement which doesn't work.  It's giving me an error on the WHERE clause.

```
UPDATE `mydb`.`mytable` WHERE `Time_Stamp`
BETWEEN '2014-12-31 00:00:00'
    AND '2014-11-31 06:00:00'
IF `my_Column` > x Then
    `my_Column` = y
End IF;
```

Even if it does accept the WHERE clause, I'm not sure the IF statement will work following on from that.  As you can see I'm a learner.  So any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE mydb.mytable 
SET my_Column = CASE WHEN my_Column > x THEN y ELSE x END
WHERE Time_Stamp BETWEEN '2014-12-31 00:00:00' AND '2014-11-31 06:00:00'
```